# Why does my photo captured in portrait change to landscape?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have this cameraView and on top of it I have this UIImageView. The UIImageView is basically a filter that changes the color of the cameraView. I was able to take a picture with the code below and the output image changes the portrait image to landscape. Why does that happen? Thanks!

```
@IBAction func takePicture(_ sender: Any) {

let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

}


func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: 
AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)

let image = renderer.image { ctx in
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

}


if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

let newImage = self.composite(image:cameraImage, overlay: image, scaleOverlay:true)
captureImageView.image = newImage

    }
  }
}

//combine imageview with uiview

func composite(image:UIImage, overlay:(UIImage), scaleOverlay: Bool = false)->UIImage?{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
image.draw(in: rect)
if scaleOverlay == false {
    rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlay.size.width, height: overlay.size.height)
}
overlay.draw(in: rect)
return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Comment: Because `UIImage(data: imageData)` pays no attention to the orientation?

Comment: How would i solve this then?

Comment: I'm asking _you_. Is the cause of the problem the fact that `UIImage(data:)` ignores orientation info? If so, maybe _you_ should look at the orientation info.

Comment: No its not that beacuse I could actually get rid of the composite func and call it like this: `captureImage.image = image` and the output image still changes to landscape.

Comment: Right but my point is that you are still not thinking about how the _device_ is oriented. What I do is look at `UIDevice.current.orientation` before display.